# Creating Swap Chain causes Window Handle to become Invalid

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, handle, direct3d11

I'm trying to work with both Direct2D and Direct3D. Right now, I'm having Direct2D draw content to a separate Device Context (with an HDC) and then copy the contents of that Device Context into my window. I could show the code I use to set that up in an edit to this post if requested, but before Direct3D gets involved, that part works.

Here is a simplified version of the Window Drawing code I use.

```
        if (d3dEngine.Get())   // Object used to hold Direct3D Resources (.Get() returns a pointer for a null check)
        {
            // d3dEngine->PrepareScene(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Wheat));
        }
        
        // Drawing Board holds the Direct 2D Render Target
        drawingBoard->GetRenderer()->BeginDraw();
        drawingBoard->GetRenderer()->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));

        mainPage->Draw(); // Main Page Holds various objects that draw to Direct2D

        if (d3dEngine.Get())
            d3dEngine->FinalizeScene();

        drawingBoard->GetRenderer()->EndDraw();

        // Get the Secondary Device Context that Direct2D draws to
        HDC dc = drawingBoard->GetDc();

        RECT r{ 0,0,0,0 };
        int err = 0;

        // Retrieve the Rectangle for the window (currentWindow is the window handle used)
        if(!GetClientRect(currentWindow, &r))
            err = GetLastError();

        // Use the BitBlt function to copy Direct2D content into a window
        if (!BitBlt(GetDC(currentWindow), r.left, r.top, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top, dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
            err = GetLastError();
```

Before any Direct3D resources are created (and the *d3dEngine.Get()* call returns null), this code runs to my satisfaction.

However, following the creation of Direct3D resources, the code fails:

```
        RECT r{ 0,0,0,0 };
        int err = 0;

        // Retrieve the Rectangle for the window (currentWindow is the window handle used)
        if(!GetClientRect(currentWindow, &r))
            err = GetLastError();
```

The window handle *currentWindow* becomes invalid as *GetLastError()* returns 1400 after the call to *GetClientRect*. I suspect that the Swap Chain in Direct3D 11 may play a role due to the following code used to activate Direct3D.

```
    GetClientRect(window, &Location);

    unsigned int width = Location.right - Location.left,
        height = Location.bottom - Location.top;

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE dTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE//, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP
    };
    int tTypes = ARRAYSIZE(dTypes);
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL dLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0
    };
    int tLevels = ARRAYSIZE(dLevels);


    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDescription;



    // Initialize the swap cahin
    swapChainDescription.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.Width = Location.right - Location.left;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.Height = Location.bottom - Location.top;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 30;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    swapChainDescription.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDescription.OutputWindow = window;
    swapChainDescription.Windowed = true;
    swapChainDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDescription.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDescription.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDescription.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_GDI_COMPATIBLE;
    swapChainDescription.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;// DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    unsigned int flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

    /// Other initialization Code
    HRESULT results = 0;
    // Initialize ID3D11Device "graphicsDevice"
    IDXGISwapChain* sc = nullptr;

    results = dxFact->CreateSwapChain(graphicsDevice, &swapChainDescription, &sc);
```

This code is in a different class than the Window drawing code towards the beginning.

The *window* variable in the Direct3D code holds the same value that *currentWindow* holds in the Window Code.

Is there anyone who could provide insight as to what is going on and why the window handle stops working? And perhaps suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still unsure why the window handle seemed to be useless when I checked, I was able to develop a workaround.

Basically, I have my Window class hold a RECT indicating the size of the Window and I use that instead of getting the RECT from the Window every time.

```
        RECT r{ 0,0,0,0 };
        int err = 0;

        // Retrieve the Rectangle for the window (currentWindow is the window handle used)
        if(!GetClientRect(currentWindow, &r))
            err = GetLastError();

        // Use the BitBlt function to copy Direct2D content into a window
        if (!BitBlt(GetDC(currentWindow), r.left, r.top, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top, dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
            err = GetLastError();


        // Now, it uses a 'size' attribute
        int err = 0;

        if (!BitBlt(GetTWindowDc(), size.left, size.top, size.right - size.left, size.bottom - size.top, dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
            err = GetLastError();
```

When it comes to getting the Window Device Context, the new *GetTWindowDc()* method takes care of that:

```
    if (d3dEngine.Get())
        return d3dEngine->GetDC();
    return GetDC(currentWindow);
```

Basically, if Direct3D is activated, the 3D manager object (which holds a DXGISurface) retrieves the HDC from Direct3D to use.

```
HDC TWindowEngine::GetDC()
{
    if (!surface.Get()) // My Unique Smart pointer to a DXGISurface1 object
        return 0;
    HDC dc;
    assert(SUCCEEDED(surface->GetDC(FALSE, &dc)));
    return dc;
}
```

According to [Surface-GetDc Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgisurface1-getdc), you need to call the corresponding *ReleaseDc* on the DXGISurface1 object. So this is how I do it.

In the Window Draw code:

```
        if (!BitBlt(GetTWindowDc(), size.left, size.top, size.right - size.left, size.bottom - size.top, dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
            err = GetLastError();
        FlushDc();
```

Here is the *FlushDc* method:

```
void TWindow::FlushDc()
{
    if (d3dEngine.Get())
        d3dEngine->ClearDC();
}
```

And the *ClearDC* method is impelented.

```
void TWindowEngine::ClearDC()
{
    if (surface.Get())
        surface->ReleaseDC(nullptr);
}
```